# Unable to add elements in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, serial-port, node-serialport

I am trying to adding the available ports on my pc for serial communication between Arduino and the computer. I have created portsList as an array variable and I am pushing those ports in that variable. But at the end, I am getting array length as 0. I am using the serial port node module.

```
const SerialPort = require("serialport");

var portsList = [];
SerialPort.list().then((ports) => {
  ports.forEach((port) => {

    var portInfo = {
      portPath: port.path,
      portManufacturer: port.manufacturer,
    };

    portsList.push(portInfo);
    console.log("Port: ", portInfo);
  });
});

console.log(portsList.length);
```

The output of the code is: [image: here]

Comment: `SerialPort.list()` is async. Your `console.log` is executed before it, thus the array is still empty.

Comment: Then how can I add an element in the array if the serialPort.list() is an async function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    portsList.push({
      portPath: port.path,
      portManufacturer: port.manufacturer,
    });
    console.log("Port: ", portInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

SerialPort.list() seems to be async. Put the console after the "forEach"

```
const SerialPort = require("serialport");

var portsList = [];
SerialPort.list().then((ports) => {
  ports.forEach((port) => {

    var portInfo = {
      portPath: port.path,
      portManufacturer: port.manufacturer,
    };

    portsList.push(portInfo);
    console.log("Port: ", portInfo);
  });
  console.log(portsList.length);
});
```

or wait for the list,

```
const SerialPort = require("serialport");
     
const getPortsList = async () => {
  var portsList = [];
  const ports = await SerialPort.list();

  ports.forEach((port) => {

    var portInfo = {
      portPath: port.path,
      portManufacturer: port.manufacturer,
    };

    portsList.push(portInfo);
    console.log("Port: ", portInfo);
  });

  console.log(portsList.length);
}

getPortsList();
```